# The number of annual revisits to the acquired satellite is in the Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have obtained the list of satellite names and the number of revisits through the aggregate_histogram function, but I do not know how to obtain the annual visit times and output them as CSV.
I have captured images and printed out the number of visits to different sensors each year, but I want to make the data more standardized and printed out as a table.

```
var oliCol = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR');
var etmCol= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR');
var tmCol= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR');
var colFilter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.bounds(aoi),
  ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 50),
  ee.Filter.lt('GEOMETRIC_RMSE_MODEL', 10),
  ee.Filter.or(
    ee.Filter.eq('IMAGE_QUALITY', 9),
    ee.Filter.eq('IMAGE_QUALITY_OLI', 9)
  ));
function fmask(img) {
  var cloudShadowBitMask = 1 << 3;
  var cloudsBitMask = 1 << 5;
  var qa = img.select('pixel_qa');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return img.updateMask(mask);
}
oliCol = oliCol.filter(colFilter);
etmCol= etmCol.filter(colFilter);
tmCol= tmCol.filter(colFilter);
var naip2012 = oliCol.merge(etmCol).merge(tmCol);
var time = ["1984","1985","1986","1987","1988",
  "1989","1990","1991","1992","1993","1994","1995","1996",
  "1997","1998","1999","2000","2001","2002","2003","2004",
  "2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012",
  "2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020"];
var list =ee.String(' ')
for(var index in time){
  {
  var year = time[index]+"-01"+"-01"
  var yearend = time[index]+"-12"+"-31"
  var count = ee.String.encodeJSON(naip2012.filterDate(year,yearend)
                               .aggregate_histogram('SATELLITE'));
  }
 var list = list.cat(count)
}
var list = ee.List(list)
print(list)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a6b329f8348481b22e558c4e959b804d

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please do not open a duplicate question (https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/376306/8104) from one that has been closed. You should edit your original question to improve it and then vote to reopen.

Comment: Sorry, I have deleted the problem by mistake and can't edit it any more.

Comment: Since you deleted your question, you can also undelete it in the same place. If that doesn't work, click "flag" and "in need of moderator intervention" and explain the problem.

Comment: Thanks, for the first time using this platform, I have clicked "flag".

Comment: One more thing: please include formatted code pertinent to the question in the body of the question rather than only a link to the code in GEE. This will allow the question to persist even if the link goes 404.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I have added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a feature collection (which is the type of data you can export as CSV in GEE) using the following. It will make a feature per year, and add the number of images for each collection (LS-5,7,8) also as a property.

```
// Calculate the number of images for every year
var listYears = ee.List.sequence(1982, 2020, 1);

// map over the years, get collection size per year and return as feature
var feats = ee.FeatureCollection(listYears.map(function(year){
  // set start and end date from the year
  var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1);
  var end = ee.Date.fromYMD(ee.Number(year).add(1), 1, 1);
  
  // filter the collections and calcualte its sizes
  var oliColSize = oliCol.filter(colFilter).filterDate(start, end).size();
  var etmColSize = etmCol.filter(colFilter).filterDate(start, end).size();
  var tmColSize = tmCol.filter(colFilter).filterDate(start, end).size();
  
  // Return the size in a feature
  var feat = ee.Feature(null, {year: year, 'system:time_start': start.millis(),
                LANDSAT_5: tmColSize, LANDSAT_7: etmColSize, LANDSAT_8: oliColSize});
  return feat;
}));
```

Then you can export that as a CSV using:

```
// export as CSV
Export.table.toDrive(feats, 'Landsat_images_perYear', 'FOLDER', null, 
                     'CSV', ['LANDSAT_5', 'LANDSAT_7', 'LANDSAT_8','year'])
```

See an example code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3714eb0ff5f84e988600f75d9b3cd3f7), including a way to graph it directly in the GEE editor.

Comment: Very good solution！Thank you for your guidance!